# Compiling Pianobar on the Pi gcrypt.h not found

Tags: raspbian

I was trying to compile Pianobar on the raspberry pi, for the purposes of modifying the source code.

Alas, the one problem I have left to a successful compilation (according to the output of `make`) is `gcrypt.h not found`.

I followed the build instructions [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5648) - note the `sudo apt-get install libevent-pthreads-2.0-5 libao-dev gnutls-dev libmad0-dev libfaad-dev libjson0-dev pkg-config`, which didn't take too much effort.

The problem is I seem to need gcrypt, and if my brand new Raspbian distribution has it, I sure can't find it!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thank you guys! I actually figured this out some time before you answered with a`apt-cache search gcrypt` command. Perhaps for general edification you could mention that in your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be libgcrypt11-dev that you need.

Comment: Here is the command to install it: sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev and more info can be found on the Raspberry Pi forum http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=33508